# Optimize regex matching m:n lists (multiple words lists agains multiple lists)

Tags: regex, perl

I have big word lists which look like this (this data is coming from db):

```
[
    {
        keyword => 'bmw.*red.*1999',
        owner => 'someone'
        #... other attributes
    },
    {
        keyword => 'toyota.*black.*1999',
        owner => 'someone else'
        #... other attributes
    },
    # and so on ... up to 300 different keywords in a list
]
```

I have to regularly match "keyword" against many other lists. Because this keyword list is used every time I compile "keyword" to regexp:

```
map { $_->{_compiled} = qr/$_->{keyword}/i } @keywords;
```

and compare every keyword with every element in other lists:

```
foreach my $other in (@other) {
    foreach my $keword (@keywords) {
        if ($other->{name} =~ $keyword->{_compiled}) {
              ## do something with $other and $keyword
        }
    }
}
```

These operations should run every 10 minutes and there should be around 50 keyword lists (with up to 300 elements) and 50 other lists which are checked against these keywords. And it should grow.

I would like to optimise matching speed as much as possible and I have two ideas/problems:

- save compiled regexp ($keyword->{_compiled}) in the database for later usage but I am not sure how much this helps (I did not do any benchmark)
- join all "keywords" or "_compiled" to one big regexp  and compare everything in one step.

code:

```
my @compiled = grep { $_->{_compiled} } @keywords;

# or is this better?
my $rx = "(".(join "|", grep { $_->{keyword} } @keywords).")";
my $compiled = qr/$rx/i;

foreach my $other in (@other) {
   if ($other->{name} =~ @compiled) {
       ## do something with $other and $keyword
       ## 
       ## but now there is no way to get "owner" of matched keyword

   }
}
```

My "problem" is that I have to be able to use "owner" and other attributes of the matched keyword. If I join everything in one big regexp or put _compiled in an array I am not able to match

Is there "best solution" to regexp-compare large lists with large lists? I am not even sure should I worry about performance problems but lists will grow and I would like to be prepared.

Comment: I've done a benchmark (I didn't remember wich question in SO it was) that compared one big regex with alternation and many small independant regex, the winner was many small regex by a factor of about 30%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to change : `bmw.*red.*1999` to

```
\bbmw\b(?>[^r]++|\Br|r(?!ed))++\bred\b(?>[^1]++|\B1|1(?!999))++\b1999\b
```

and the same for all keywords. The goal with this change is to fail faster as possible.

Note that the transformation can be automated with 2 successive search/replace (it is always the same)

```
search: (\w+)
replace: \b$1\b

search: \.\*(?=\\b(\w)(\w+)\\b)
replace: (?>[^$1]++|\B$1|$1(?!$2\b))++
```

example with the second keyword

```
toyota.*black.*1999
first replace:
\btoyota\b.*\bblack\b.*\b1999\b
second replace:
\btoyota\b(?>[^b]++|\Bb|b(?!lack\b))++\bblack\b(?>[^1]++|\B1|1(?!999\b))++\b1999\b
```

Then you store the compiled expression in your database.

Comment: +1 because I really like the idea. "bmw" does not have to be a single word but it can be a part of a word but your regex could be adapted. so you think that it would be useful to save compiled expression?

Comment: @storyteller: The general idea of the new pattern is to add anchors (\b) and all the constraints you can (possessive quantifiers, atomic groups, reduced character classes) instead of a permissive `.*` that can cause many backtracks. For compiled expressions, i think you have nothing to loose.